# Excel sort numbers with letter prefix

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a column:

```
a1
a10
a11
a12
a13
a14
a15
a16
a17
a18
a19
a2
a20
a21
a22
a23
a24
a25
a26
a27
a28
a29
a3
a30
a31
a4
a5
a6
a7
a8
a9
```

But I need to sort it like this:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13....
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column A, put this formula in column B (or wherever is handy) and sort by it:

```
=LEFT(A1,1) & TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,1),""),"00")
```

This assumes that you have one character in each cell in column A, followed by a number.

Comment: + 1 need to mention that the user needs to copy and Paste Special Values before sorting :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I just tested it with my solution (which is more or less the same as Doug's) - and you don't need to paste the values first! :-)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, me neither!

Comment: @DougGlancy: I see what you mean :) I was only sorting col B... How Dumb :|

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of an option that allows you to sort the way you like - however, you could help yourself with a a helper column that extracts the number - and then sort both columns by this column (and delete the helper column afterwards if you wish.

Assuming your text would always be `a`, you could extract the number with this formula: `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))`.

In case you have different strings, use this formula:

```
=1*MID(A2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(A2,ROW($1:$9),1)),0),COUNT(1*MID(A2,ROW($1:$9),1)))
```

You need to enter it as an array formula, i.e. instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Credits for the latter formula go [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/extracting-numbers-from-alphanumeric-strings-HA001154901.aspx).

Comment: Yup this would have worked too! Thank you so much you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Copy your column somewhere with a spare column to its immediate right, split that added column Fixed width at the first character with Text to Columns and use the numbers-only column for sorting.